# Getting "The RUNAS command is not supported." when using runas on iexplore.exe

Tags: runas

When attempting to run IE on Windows Server 2008 under different user accounts using the runas command I get the message "The RUNAS command is not supported." This command works fine for other applications, but not for IE. Anyone else run into this & find a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is not possible under Vista / Server 2008.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922980

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about your environment but that feature DOES work on an otb `windows 2008 R2` server. You can hold `shift+right click` on the icon and select run as different user. Are you trying to launch `iexplore.exe` from the a command prompt or remote shell?